# UWP Unit Testing cannot access Application Resources

Tags: unit-testing, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm pretty new to UWP and I need to unit test a service located in the UI project of the application. This service gets host name and port settings from the App.xaml file of the UI project.
When I run the unit test for this service, the unit test application environment has trouble accessing the Application Resources dictionary (I copied the host name and port settings to the xaml file of the UnitTest project).

Any ideas ?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far. That way people can use it to reproduce the problem and give much better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your actual code, but have you tried running you unit test code in the UI thread? This works for me when I'm testing UWP code reading .resw resource files. Here is a code snippet using xUnit in UWP unit test project:

```
    [Fact]
    public async void ShouldPass()
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
            Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
            {
                // --> your unit test code goes here <--
            });
    }
```